# Does a default/vanilla MySQL installation keep a log of run queries?

Tags: mysql, logging

I've just installed MySQL on a VM with XAMPP and I was wondering if this default installation keeps a log of run queries.

For example, to access my database, I visit:

```
localhost/phmypadmin
```

Comment: For example, using phpmyadmin, I modified a value of a column. Does MySQL keep a log of this change?

Comment: Thanks for asking this - I was curious about it too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not by default. You have to change some settings, as per the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html).